# How to swap the first value of the first column in a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which i have 3 columns where first and last are dates.So what i  want that i will interchange the 1st column date with the last one only for the first row.Other rows will be as usual.Dates will be dynamic

Table

```
MyTable 
DateAdded1   Name  DateAdded2
 2015-01-23  A      2015-03-12
 2015-02-13  B      2013-03-19
 2015-04-23  C      2015-03-12
```

Now my requirement is that  i will interchange  the  2015-03-12 date in the place of 2015-01-23 other rows will same .Please someone help me.

Comment: You have a primary key ?

Comment: Thats a big mistake you should have one primary key to avoid these situations.

Answer (score 0):

It may helps you

```
    update mytable 
    set dateadded1 =(select dateadded2 from mytable where Name  ='A'
, dateadded2 =(select dateadded1 from mytable where Name  ='A')
    where Name  ='A'
```

Comment: but it is one query i doing something with the data how i will declare this way i show dates somewhere

Comment: sorry i didnt get you can you elaborate

Comment: I want that functionality in one query only

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with one query:

```
update tbl
join
(select DateAdded2,
       name,
       DateAdded1
from tbl limit 1)q
on tbl.name=q.name
set tbl.DateAdded1=q.DateAdded2,
    tbl.DateAdded2=q.DateAdded1;
```

You can [check it.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d32d9/1)